# Networking - internet connection

Tags: networking

my internet connection only allows me to login into skype but not to browse the internets. is it possible for me to route all the http traffic through skype or maybe through the ports skype uses?

Comment: Can you add "route" command output please?

Comment: @RecNes, I think the OP may need a little bit of help on how to do that...

Comment: Is something broken on your computer? If so, we should concentrate on fixing what is broken, rather than an ill-conceived work-around. Is this a restriction imposed by an administrator? If so, it's an even worse idea to attempt to bypass your organization's policy. It's the kind of thing that results in severe disciplinary action.

Comment: Maybe your "ISP" is blocking all http traffic on purpose. Perhaps you could just use an SSH SOCKS proxy. If you're not familiar with ssh, maybe look for another solution - something sensible, like finding out why you can't transmit regular http traffic, if that's even what's going on..?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Skype uses an IP adress (at least as backup). So probably the DNS is mixed up. @Tendai: what operating system are you using? can you please execute `ping 8.8.4.4` in your linux-terminal or windows cmd.exe and afterwards please `ping www.google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Skype does not have the ability to reroute your internet traffic. Usually when you can get software like skype running but cannot access the internet, your web browser is the most likely source of the problem. With Internet Explorer open, click on Tools -> Internet Options and then on the 'advanced' tab. Amongst the list of checkboxes you will see an option called 'enable third party extensions'. Try removing the checkmark there and then click 'apply'. Then close your internet explorer browser and re-open it. If your internet access starts working then a third part program like a toolbar or malware was preventing your access. If the internet access still does not come through you will want to see if you are getting DNS resolution as stated by @Walter Maier-Murdnelch . Click on your start button and click on the 'Run'command. In the run box type 'CMD' and hit enter. When the black window appears type in 'ping yahoo.com'. If you start getting replies then Internet Explorer itself may be damaged and need reinstalling. If the replies do not come back you may need to flush your DNS using the 'ipconfig /flushdns' command in the same window. If for some reason it still does not work after that, you may need your Internet Service Provider to check the issue.

Comment: +1for PING and checking DNS